# Why webClient doesn't do any http call?

Tags: java, httprequest, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, spring-reactive

I have following code:

```
 List<Mono<MyResponseDTO>> monoList = queue.stream()
                .map(jobStatusBunch -> webClient
                        .post()
                        .uri("localhost:8080/api/some/url")
                        .bodyValue(convertToRequestDto(someBean))
                        .retrieve()
                        .toEntity(String.class)
                        .filter(HttpEntity::hasBody)
                        .map(stringResponseEntity -> {
                            try {
                                return objectMapper.readValue(stringResponseEntity.getBody(), MyResponseDTO.class);
                            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                                log.error("Can't parse", e);
                                return null;
                            }
                        })
                        .doOnNext(myResponseDTO -> {
                            log.info("doOnNext is invoked");
                        })
                ).collect(Collectors.toList());
        //await when all MONOs are completed
        Mono<Void> mono = Flux.fromIterable(monoList).then();
        mono.subscribe(aVoid -> {
            log.info("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        });
```

webClient  instantiantion:

```
this.webClient = WebClient.builder().build();
```

My aim allow to execute all http requests from queue in parallel and await when all of them are finished. But despite the fact that queue is not empty actual http call is not happen. Could you explain why and how to fix it?

### UPDATE

Thanks @caco3  for advice. I corrected code like this:

```
log.info("Start waiting for {}", monoList);
Mono<Void> mono = Flux.fromIterable(monoList)
        .flatMap(Function.identity())
        .then();
log.info("Finished waiting for {}", monoList);
```

and I see following log:

```
2019-11-19 19:17:17.733  INFO 5896 --- [   scheduling-1] c.b.m.service.MyService     : Start waiting for [MonoPeek]
2019-11-19 19:17:25.988  INFO 5896 --- [   scheduling-1] c.b.m.service.MyService     : Finished waiting for [MonoPeek]
2019-11-19 19:17:26.015 TRACE 5896 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [c42c1c2] HTTP POST localhost:8080/api/some/url, headers={}
2019-11-19 19:17:48.230  INFO 5896 --- [tor-http-nio-11] c.b.m.service.MyService     : doOnNext is invoked
```

So current code doesn't await all reqests termination.But I really need it

Comment: Probably, you meant to flatten the `Flux`: `Flux.fromIterable(monoList).flatMap(Function.identity()).then()`

Comment: @caco3 yes - you are correct. But **doOnNext** callback is invoking after **.then** and even after **.subscribe**

Comment: Sure, the work is happening on another thread. If you want to log the termination you can use the [`doAfterTerminate`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#doAfterTerminate-java.lang.Runnable-) operator

Comment: @caco3 my aim is await the request completition. I want synchronous operstion.

Comment: Then you can `block` on the `Mono`

Comment: @caco3 will it work together with doOnNext callback?

Comment: @caco3 where to call  .block()?

Comment: Blocking after `then()` should do what you want

Comment: but what if exception was thrown?

Comment: You mean signaled? The exception would be thrown on the `block()` call